# Completely Clear Workbook has 5 MB Size

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have completely Clear Excel File. it has 5 MB size I can't find a problem. I have the same problem with a work-related file.

https://ufile.io/xsvqd

On the link, you can download the file.

Comment: One method which I sometimes follow is to post working range on Text Editor Note Tab Light and delete the sheet and then transfer back data to Excel  from Note Tab on a new sheet. Other method I follow is to copy desired data Range to New Worksheet and delete the old sheet. Your link to file download is not working otherwise I could have checked the reason for it.

Comment: Following methods can help Directly reduce file size
1. Remove “blank space” in your sheets
2. Check for and delete unnecessary hidden sheets
3. Save your files in binary format (.xlsb)
4. Remove formatting on raw data
5. Double check Conditional Formatting ranges

Comment: We Have tried that via Note++ and far manager but no use. w have deleted and cleared it via VBA too. I can use other upload or email whatever is convenient for you. here is another link.  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04524784539993163581

Comment: in woorkshit iam talkgin about there is no data there is no formating, no values. nothing. its completely clear

Comment: I saved file as DOS Txt file then reopened in Excel as Tab delimited text file which I saved Excel File giving a sie of just 10 KB.

Comment: our file reduced size <https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hdqgaqhyt2bu77/Book1.xlsx?dl=0>

Comment: Could you do a search of your C:\ drive for `Sheet.xl*` and `Book.xl*`.  If you find one, how big is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think this is Excels Bug: If you will hide for example all rows starting 10th and then you will click via mouse on the thin line for unhiding. if you will click unhide there will be only last row. others will be still hidden. after you will unhide others and save file you will get 2.5 MB size of excel [image]file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do a test . If you shift `Control` plus `End` you will reach to Row No. 1048576 but If you take a new work book and fill range "A1:J15" you will reach Cell "J15" . This shows the effect of previous data and formats, auto filters.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ctrl+end on Info worksheet the you get to E1048576. If you tap ctrl+end on the RC-C worksheet you go to XFD1048576.

**Info worksheet**

Select all rows 1:1048576 on Info worksheet and set for standard height of 14.3.

Use ctrl+home then ctrl+shift+end to grab the used range.

Use Home, Edit, Clear, Clear All the selection.

Save workbook.

Result file size: 2.9Mb.

**RC-C worksheet**

Select all rows 1:1048576 on RC-C worksheet and set for standard height of 14.3.

Use ctrl+home then ctrl+shift+end to grab the used range.

Use Home, Edit, Clear, Clear All the selection.

Save workbook.

Result file size: 233kb.

Answer (score 0):

**If only on sheet had data:**

1. Press the arrow indicated in photo to select whole sheet
2. Right click
3. Delete

[image]

**Delete with VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook

        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            ws.Cells.Delete
        Next ws

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @giorgilomidze did you try this solution?